# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to integrate Ionic framework?

Tags: android, angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic-framework

I am trying to add the [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com) to my app.

For this purpose I have downloaded the "starter template" from the ionic website. The app's index.html file seems to be running on the browser correctly and without any problem. But after building it for the Android environment, the app shows only a white screen with nothing in it.

The following is the Worklight project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54761340/angulartest.zip

Comment: Edit your question with: Worklight version, Logs from LogCat when running the app, steps you've taken to integrate the framework, link to the framework's website, anything else you did not tell us.

Comment: Also upload the Worklight project, not the generated Android project.

Comment: The uploaded zip file is the worklight project not the generate android project. The ionic frameworks website is as follows,....

Comment: Something is missing in this zip, when importing to Eclipse it does not import anyting but the android project.

Comment: To make the zip file I just exported the worklight project as a zip file.Is this the right way to do it ??

Comment: Make sure that you "export as project": http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/

Comment: Just uploaded the new zip file

Comment: see my answer. Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand how this was running anywhere, as the HTML is borked:

- duplicate `HTML` and `BODY` elements
- incorrect placement of references to .css and .js files...

Do the following:

1. Open `angulartest\apps\angulartestapp\common\index.html` and replace its contents with the following:

   > ```
   > <!DOCTYPE html>
   > <html ng-app="ionicApp">
   >   <head>
   >       <meta charset="UTF-8">
   >       <title>Ionic</title>
   >       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
   >       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
   >       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
   >       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionic.min.css">
   >       <script src="js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
   >       <script>
   >           window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
   >       </script>
   >   </head>
   >
   >   <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   >       <ion-header-bar title="myTitle"></ion-header-bar>
   >       <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
   >           <h2>Content</h2>
   >       </ion-content>
   >
   >       <script src="js/index.js"></script>
   >       <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
   >       <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   >       <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
   >   </body>
   > </html>
   > ```
2. Right-click on the angulartestapp folder and choose Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
3. Right-click on the generated Android projet and choose Run As > Android application

I've tested it in Worklight Console's MBS as well as Android Emulator. Seems to be working, whatever it is...

Answer (score 0):

```
<body id='content'>
</body>
```

it will conflict with worklight.

you just try to remove the id='content' and try again.

but this may make that deviceReady() function will not be ready forever.